# How can I download a file from the web to the server side in Nodejs and send it to the client side in ReactJs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am doing a web app using ReactJS and Nodejs. I would like the user to download a file without knowing the url and changing the name of the file. So, What I thought to do was to download the file in server side first and then when the download is finsished to give the user the ability to download the file in the client side using React.

What I have done right now is to download the file in server side, but I cannot find a way to continue.

NodeJs Code:

```
app.get("/api/download/", async (req, res) => {
  const url = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500";
  const path = Path.resolve("file.zip");
  const response = await Axios({
    method: "GET",
    url: url,
    responseType: "stream"
  });

  response.data.pipe(FS.createWriteStream(path));
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    response.data.on("end", () => {
         resolve();
    });

    response.data.on("error", err => {
      reject(err);
    });
  });
});

app.get("/api/downloadfile", function(req, res) {
  var path = "file.zip";
  res.download(path);
});
```

React Code:

```
  download = async event => {
    await fetch("/api/download");
    await fetch("api/downloadfile").then(response => {
      response.blob().then(blob => {
        let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        let a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = url;
        a.download = "file.zip";
        a.click();
      });
    });
  };
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! This is not my code for client side. This is written in nodejs for the server side.

Comment: What does your React code look like?

Comment: I update the code, and I added the missing parts. I am really new to this, so there are probably silly mistakes